# Orderby LINQ stackoverflow exception. Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.

Tags: c#, linq

Orderby LINq stackoverflow exception

1. I have a tree folder which user may check all and display data into grid. The tree is being constructed via column definition and data is being cosntructed via LINQ.

The LINQ is very long that takes in dynamic select, dynamic where and dynamic orderby. All are being passed as string. It works well until all folders are selected and ordered by, that is the time it gives the stackoverflow exception. But when the orderby is removed, it started working again. Removing orderby is out of the question.

How can I prevent this from happening with out having to remove it?

I tried separating the orderby from the whole linq with select and where. The error gets in during the call of this line:

```
string test = OrderByString(_selectQuery);
            IEnumerable allRowsOrderedBy = allDataRows.AsQueryable().OrderBy(test);//this line throws exception
            return allRowsOrderedBy;
```

OrdebryString is just a method that parses my select query so I can pass it to the orderby:
an excerpt of what was constructed is this string:

> "contact_title,contact_firstname,contact_middlename,contact_lastname,contact_preferredname,contact_code,contact_sex,contact_hold,contact_organization,contact_organizationname,contact_home_address_1_"

....

There is no stacktrace, just this error:

> {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack
>   overflow state.}

Comment: So then don't order by so much stuff.  You're apparently blowing the stack when you try.  Incidentally this is exactly why you should avoid recursive solutions when you can; stack space is quite small.

Comment: Not ordering it by is out of the question. Reason is I am just replicating the behavior of an existing desktop application (we had to convert it to web app), the app is ordered by up to last column of the tree selected. If I don't do exactly, the QA doesn't pass it coz they only base from what can be seen in the desktop app result. Any other suggestion? tnx

Comment: You will obviously have to find some other way to order the data. Stack space is not infinite; if your chosen implementation exceeds the available stack space, it simply won't work. You can try running the operation in a custom thread, for which you've specified extra stack space (IIRC, the default is 1MB...so, try 10MB or even 100MB), but you might just wind up pushing the failure to some later date. It's better to fix the algorithm so that it can do the ordering you want without so much recursion.

Comment: Please note that as stated so far, your question isn't very useful or answerable. There are lots of ways you _might_ be exceeding the available stack space. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reliably reproduces the problem it's not possible to know what specific implementation you have that is broken, never mind what a good way to work around the issue might be.

Comment: Is there a subset of order fields that does work? Have you tried isolating groups of order by fields to determine if it's a particular field that's causing this? Have you gotten any sorting to work for this row set? What's the performance going to be like? If this was working this way for the desktop, what's changed for your port to the web? What about the UI? It seems like there can't be any user defined sorting based on what we're discussing here. That's odd, don't you think? "Because that's the way we've always done it" is never a good reason on its own.

Comment: Yes, I have isolated it by selecting all folders in the tree but applying only 50 columns in the orderby( selecting all is around 400 columns) and it worked. What changed? the desktop app was built around 1990s using powerbuilder to be specific, I am using c# asp .net mvc.  I have tried trampoline technique but didn't help. Will try thread and see if I can make it work. tnx